# Testcafe: Inject Client Script Code into Worker Global Scope to mock a missing Web API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer, testcafe, webapi

It is easy to **inject client scripts** into window's global scope as per [official guide](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/inject-client-scripts.html#inject-script-code). What I'm having troubles is how to go about injecting client scripts into **web worker's global scope**. Goal is to mock a Web API which is supported in Chrome's web worker but not in testcafe / puppeteer.

Comment: Could you please clarify which scenario leads to failed tests? You can check [this list](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2684) in the TestCafe repository. If your scenario is not present in the list, please open a [new bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new/choose).

Comment: @VladimirA. it's BarcodeDetector API which is only available on Chrome and even than only on certain operating systems. I also had to mock some other APIs which was not a problem since I used those in main thread. Problem is how to inject something into a Worker.

Comment: @radulle, please [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new/choose) in the TestCafe GitHub repository and share a sample project that demonstrates your scenario.